# How to open three executable files using a program and navigate in between them?

Tags: navigation, exe

I've got three executable files which should open at a time. Of those, two are in C language which will open in full screen. I wrote a batch file to open all three files. However, I have to navigate between them using one key for each exe file.

Please tell me how to navigate between these three files?

P.S. As of now I'm using Alt+Tab combo, but it is not a viable solution.

Comment: Can you explain why Alt+Tab is not a viable solution?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might be perfect for you.

Comment: When I'm switching from one window to another, the C language exe files are being accessed in minimized window. I had to use the mouse to open it or press Alt+Tab combo a number of times.

Comment: @bgoldst will that program work while I'm accessing a C language exe file and try to shift to another?

Comment: Yes, each Autohotkey script runs in the background and continuously monitors for keypresses, so switching windows does not cause any problems for it.

Comment: The behavior you've described (regarding the minimization of the windows) is strange. Normally when you Alt+Tab to a window it restores immediately. Must be something weird going on with these applications. Without more details on these applications (e.g. source code) it's difficult to say what's going on.

Comment: @bgoldst will try your solution and I hope that it works.

Comment: @bgoldst Thank You Very Much! The Solution worked like a charm. In the process I also learnt about a new scripting language.